# EDIT: Data seems to be unsorted while plotting

Tags: matlab, ode, dimension, mismatch

[Click here to see  the figure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfL5F.jpg) When I run and plot `X` and solution, it seems like the data is not sorted. The previous error regarding subscripted dimension mismatch is gone now. Below is my main code:

```
      clear all
y0 = 20000; % initial conditions
iter = 0;
years = 5;
solution = [];

X = [];
for p = 1:1:years

iter = iter+1;
display(iter)
ll = 273;
ul = 273 + 91;
wl = (ul-ll).*rand(1,1) + ll;

yearlength = wl+0.1;

finaltime = p*yearlength;

t = 0:finaltime;


mugen;
Kgen;
d1gen;

n = 2;


deltat = 1;
tspan = 0:deltat:finaltime;

options = odeset('RelTol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-10);

sol = ode23s(@(t,y)para_1d(t,y,n,mug,Kg,d1g),tspan,y0,options);

X = [X sol.x];
Y = (sol.y)';
ny = length(Y);
Ytrans = Y';

solution = [solution Ytrans(1,:)] ;


%display(Ytrans(1,end))

clearvars -except solution solution1 iter  X
y0 = solution(end,end);
display(y0)
end

plot(x, solution)
```

This is the function where my ode is:

```
 function dy  = para_1d(t, y,n,  mug, Kg, d1g)

  count = ceil(t)+1;

  dy(1,1)  =  (mug(count).*(y(1).^n)/(Kg(count).^n+y(1).^n)) - d1g(count).*y(1);
```

and the parameter files are:

```
x1 = [0  91.25 91.26  182.5 182.51 273.75 273.76 wl];
clear x

for n = 1:p;
    x(n,:) = (n-1)*(wl+0.1) + x1;
end
   counter = 0;  
for j=1:p
    for i=1:8
        counter = counter+1;
        xnew(counter) = x(j,i);
    end
end
y1 = [500  500  1500 1500   500 500 0 0];
clear y
for n = 1:p;
    y(n,:) =  y1;
end
    counter = 0;
    for j = 1:p
        for i = 1:8
            counter = counter+1;
            ynew(counter) = y(j,i);
        end 
    end
    w = y(1,:);
    for l = 2:p
        w = [w y(l,:)];
    end
     v = x(1,:);
    for q = 2:p
        v = [v x(q,:)];
    end


  mug = pchip(v,w,t);
```

The parameter `K` is:

```
x1 = [0  91.25 91.26  182.5 182.51 273.75 273.76 wl];
clear x
for n = 1:p;
    x(n,:) = (n-1)*(wl + 0.1) + x1;
end
   counter = 0;  
for j = 1:p
    for i = 1:8
        counter = counter + 1;
        xnew(counter) = x(j,i);
    end
end
%y1 = [8000 8000 27000 27000 8000  8000  6000 6000 ];
%y1 = [8000 8000 12000 12000 8000  8000  6000 6000 ];
 y1 = [6000 6000 8000 8000 6000  6000  6000 6000 ];
clear y
for n = 1:p;
    y(n,:) =  y1;
end
    counter = 0;
    for j = 1:p
        for i = 1:8
            counter = counter+1;
            ynew(counter) = y(j,i);
        end 
    end
     w = y(1,:);
    for l = 2:p
        w = [w y(l,:)];
    end
     v = x(1,:);
    for q = 2:p
        v = [v x(q,:)];
    end

  Kg = pchip(v,w,t);
```

and the last parameter is:

```
x1 = [0  91.25 91.26  182.5 182.51 273.75 273.76 wl];
clear x
for n=1:p;
    x(n,:) = (n-1)*(wl + 0.1) + x1;
end
   counter=0;  
for j=1:p
    for i=1:8
        counter=counter+1;
        xnew(counter) = x(j,i);
    end
end
y1 = [ 0.02272  0.02272 0.04  0.04  0.02272 0.02272  0.005263 0.005263 ];
clear y
for n=1:p;
    y(n,:) =  y1;
end
    counter=0;
    for j=1:p
        for i=1:8
            counter=counter+1;
            ynew(counter) = y(j,i);
        end 
    end
     w=y(1,:);
    for l=2:p
        w=[w y(l,:)];
    end
     v=x(1,:);
    for q=2:p
        v=[v x(q,:)];
    end

  d1g = pchip(v,w,t);
```

You can simply look at the main code and suggest me where I am doing mistake. The parameter codes and ode file is only for those who want to run the code for a clearer view. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: The error message tells you the line number. Where does the error occur?

Comment: `solution(iter,:) = Ytrans(1,:);`, as advertised. There's no way to add line numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to add line numbers in the code. Error occurs at "{solution(iter,:) = Ytrans(1,:); % This is where it gives me error at iter=2;}". I mentioned it in the code as well.

Comment: Okay, now I found the critical line. Is it intended that the size of `Ytrans` changes?

Comment: yes, it is intended.

Comment: Using a matrix `solution` each row has to have the same amount of elements. I recommend a cell array instead. This would be `solution{iter} = Ytrans(1,:);`

Comment: I tried to correct it by creating an empty variable first. It seemed to work but when i plotted the solution, it seems that time axis is creating a problem. Let me edit the code and then please have a look.